# template cant recognize url name django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have a search field in my website header, and it doesnt reconize the url `search_result`

index.html file:

```
<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
        <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      </form>
```

urls.py:

```
path('search/', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

views.py:

```
class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'main/search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self): # new
        return Post.objects.filter(
            Q(title__icontains=q) | Q(writer__icontains=q)
        )
```

I get the error: `Reverse for 'search_results' not found. 'search_results' is not a valid view function or pattern name.`

Comment: can you try with `{% url 'app_name:search_results' %}`?

Comment: Is the app that contains `urls.py` in `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`? Is the path inside a list that is called `urlpatterns`? Is the `urls.py` either the global urls.py or added to the global urls.py?

Answer (score 1):

A newbie thought -- shouldn't the form method be "POST" instead of "GET" ?

to have this
`<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="post">`
instead of
`<form action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">`

Sorry I couldn't add comment, as not having enough points -- so posting my thoughts in this answer section..

Comment: It should not be POST, as POST is generally meant for requests that alter the database. Showing search results does not do this (usually) so I think GET is appropriate.